# How can I speed up update of Select/MultiSelect widgets in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am fairly new with bokeh and was trying to interact with my plotted data through the Select and MultiSelect widgets. I noticed that the performance significantly decreases when a long list (>34k items) is provided to the options argument for these widgets. From what I saw Select simply acts as `mylist[mylist.index('selected_value')]` and MultiSelect just as `selected_vals.append(mylist[mylist.index('selected_value')])`, so if this is actually the case I don't understand why the widgets are so slow to return their value since python can easily handle these operations with lists of any length. Although I'm working with multidimensional large datasets I'm sure the loaded data does not really play a role since I already tried to decouple the plot updates from the widgets and just print the returned value selected from the dropdown menu (this can take up to 30 seconds, and even just having the menu open can take several seconds). I tried shortening the list passed to options argument (without changing the size of the loaded data) and the widgets behave as expected. Is there a workaround/fix to this? 
Here some of the code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import Select, MultiSelect, ColumnDataSource, CDSView, GroupFilter
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis256
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure
from bokeh.transform import log_cmap

data = np.random.rand(11000, 3)
normExpr = np.random.rand(11000, 35000)
gene_names = np.array(np.random.rand(35000), dtype='str')
clusters = list(np.array(range(20), dtype='str'))
normExpr = pd.DataFrame(normExpr, columns=gene_names)
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['PHATE1', 'PHATE2', 'color'])
data['cluster'] = clusters*550
COLORS = Viridis256[::-1]
columns = list(gene_names)[:20]

def first_fig():
    s = slice(len(data['color']))
    source = ColumnDataSource(data)
    kw = dict()
    kw['title'] = "Expression of gene %s in %s" % (gene.value.title(), cluster.value.title())
    p = figure(plot_height=500, plot_width=550, tools='pan,box_zoom,hover,reset',
               toolbar_location="above", output_backend='webgl', **kw)
    p.background_fill_color="#fafafa"
    p.xaxis.axis_label = 'X-values'
    p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Y-values'
    if gene.value != 'None' and cluster.value != 'All tissue':
        view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='cluster', group=cluster.value)])
        new = normExpr[gene.value]
        source.patch({'color': [(s, new)]})
        p.circle(x='PHATE1', y='PHATE2', source=source, view=view, radius=0.002, color=log_cmap('color', COLORS, 0, 1),
                 hover_color='white', hover_alpha=0.5)

    elif gene.value == 'None' and cluster.value != 'All tissue':
        view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='cluster', group=cluster.value)])
        p.circle(x='PHATE1', y='PHATE2', source=source, view=view, radius=0.002, color="#31AADE",
                 hover_color='white', hover_alpha=0.5)
    elif gene.value != 'None' and cluster.value == 'All tissue':
        new = normExpr[gene.value]
        source.patch({'color': [(s, new)]})
        p.circle(x='PHATE1', y='PHATE2', source=source, radius=0.002, color=log_cmap('color', COLORS, 0, 1),
                 hover_color='white', hover_alpha=0.5)

    else:
        p.circle(x='PHATE1', y='PHATE2', source=source, radius=0.002, color='#31AADE',
                 hover_color='white', hover_alpha=0.5)
    return p


def update(attr, old, new):
    layout.children[1] = first_fig()


cluster = Select(title='Cluster', value='All tissue', options=['All tissue'] + clusters)
cluster.on_change('value', update)
gene = Select(title='Gene', value='None', options=['None'] + columns)
gene.on_change('value', update)


controls = column([cluster, gene], width=100)
layout = row(controls, first_fig())

curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "Gene mapping"
```

Comment: Hello @Bruno and welcome on Stack Overflow. Could you create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) focused on the issues you are facing ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion! The edited version should work. second_fig() and third_fi() funtions are not really essential and could be skipped. The problem arises if I pass the full list of gene_names in line 17 (as you notice now I'm passing only the first 20 entries). With the full list every change seem to take ages (even if its just clicking to open the dropdown menu of the select widgets).

Answer (score 0):

- First off, it should be stressed that this code gets executed, in full, for every new connection. In particular, the first "data setup" block of code at the top takes nearly 5 seconds to execute on my laptop. Bokeh is not magic, it cannot make real CPU work take less time than it takes. However, if this data can be shared (ideally read-only) between sessions, then you can use [Lifecycle Hooks](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#lifecycle-hooks) to ensure this initialization only happens *once* when the server starts. You can see a concrete use of this technique [in this example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/spectrogram)
- Next, it's worth stating the general best-practice that is always advised:

  > *Always change **as little as possible** in updates*

  A corrollary of this is:

  > *Build up plots and and layouts **once, up front**, and later only change **data***.

  This is because, Bokeh is highly optimized to handle updates to data (either to columns in a `ColumnDataSource`, or values of properties on existing objects). When you recreate everything "from scratch" as you do in your `update` function, that is an extremely inefficient way to use Bokeh. In other words, the general outline of an app is always best if it looks something like:

  ```
  p = figure(...)

  view = GroupFilter(...)
  source = ColumnDataSource(...)

  # create all the glyphs you will *ever* need up front
  # can set unused ones .visible = False

  select = Select(...)

  def update(attr, old, new):
      # Update existing source or view here, toggle .visible on glyphs, etc
      # But don't make new objects

  curdoc().add_root(column(plot, select)
  ```
- Finally, start by trying to turn off WebGL. It is currently without a maintainer and has some issues. 11k points should generally be within the realm of standard Bokeh canvas rendering, unless possibly there is much, much overlap and alpha compositing. In that case, you might want to consider [Holoviews](https://holoviews.org/) which can drive Bokeh and [Datashader](https://datashader.org/) together.

Unfortunately it is too involved for me to rewrite your entire example according to these guidelines, but hopefully they get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I just started with bokeh and basic structure of the code is based on [this](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/crossfilter/main.py) online example. So thank you for the tips to improve @bigreddot.

Comment: On the other hand I know that the data is big (and will get probably bigger in the future) so it takes some time to load at the beginning however my perplexity comes from the fact that just changing this line at the top of the code from `columns = list(gene_names)[:20]` to `columns = list(gene_names)` has such a huge impact on performance. I can't understand why cause the size of the data (and everithing else) hasn't changed. Can you please explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue ariases just when using Microsoft Edge. I changed browser to Chrome and the scripts works fine. Still can't explain the dependency of the perfomance to thee length of the list of options provided to the select widget when using Edge though.

Comment: Browsers are all very different and have different problems and issues of their own.